# implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1'

Tags: android, android-studio, paypal, payment

I am trying to run my application to process payments but I have run into this error. There are no errors within my code but I am unsure as to how to fix the issue. My code is below:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.firebase.alokraj.firebaselogin"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    // prevent error message "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'"
}
```

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta5'

//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'

// HTTP library (for Mailgun)
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
```

}

// Firebase
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$1